# Bound iPhone App to 3.5 inch Frame in iPhone 5

Tags: ios

Wrote an app for iPhone in 3.5 inch mode, and now - I need to make it work for iPhone 5 (4-inch retina).

I'm getting a little complicated with Auto-layouts and can't seem to make it work. Is there some way I can just bound the app to a 3.5 inch frame on an iPhone 5 in *the middle* of the screen (not with the ugly white space in the bottom I see now), and in that frame it would work like and iPhone 4?

I know it may not be the optimal solution, but I need to publish the app and for now it will do.

Thank

Comment: Don't do that. Rewrite your question showing what you're doing and the result (a screenshot would be good). Most likely you are over complicating the situation.

Comment: Apple made it quite clear that as of February 1st, 2014, all apps must fully support the full iPhone 5 screen as well as retina devices. Your app will be rejected if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

As the responses indicated - this should not be done.

I fought with the layouts until I made them fit 4 inch screens too. It's the only way to go.